# Check ZSH version with zsh -v: did I made a mess?

Tags: shell, zsh

I thought I could check my ZSH version used in macOS with `zsh -v`. Instead, I got a very long output which contained some shell code and I'm not sure if I made a mess with that command.

Comment: What is _my ZSH version_ : The version of that zsh you are in right now, or the version of the first zsh executable found in your PATH?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 % zsh --help | grep version
  --version  show zsh version number, then exit

 % zsh --help | grep -- '-v '
  -v    equivalent to --verbose
```

So you just run another *zsh* process, but in a verbose mode.